# Spatial query with clip (PostGIS)

Tags: postgis, clip, spatial-query

I'm making the transition from GIS to PostGIS and am stuck on this spatial query.

I have background geometry (purple, outlined red) which has an overlay of islands (blue, below); I need the area of only the islands within the red line. In GIS this would be a clip, using the purple shape as my mask.

[image: background purple shape]

[image: blue islands]

So I query using ST_Within() and obtain the green islands, which is great, but - logically - I'm missing those which are not fully within the mask:
[image: st_within result]

And I can still find those islands overlapping the boundary of my polygon using ST_Overlap() to find these pink polygons:

[image: st_overlap results in pink overlap polygons]

But is there an efficient way to get the area of the islands only within the red outline? This will cut a percentage of the island polygons, I understand, those will be associated with the adjacent background polygon.

Comment: From which GIS is it that you are transitioning?

Comment: You are looking for the ST_Intersection function https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

Comment: Thanks @ziggy! I'd looked at that part of the docs previously, but didn't understand the st_intersection(), st_intersects() relationship as @pdavis clarified below.

While it lasts, this link may help others like me who failed at RingTFM: https://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom)
```

For more info: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

Answer (score -2):

Run the script and select your islands, add semantic fields if necessary ...

`CREATE TABLE land_clip as
SELECT a.geom FROM
blue a JOIN purple b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);`

In my proposal, all the islands will be selected by a clip without crossing them, if they need to be cut, use the script from the pdavis answer ...

or try this script, but this is a bad tone of writing the script:

`CREATE TABLE land_clip as
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM
blue a, purple b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);`

So move on from jokes to business.

The surgeon is on the spot and does anesthesia: "Paul Ramsey and his creative team you are great !!!". I start a small operation: "Enough people fooling about the behavior of the function to select and cut!!!."

My first cut: "You need to create a function, for example ST_Selects (), which must completely SELECT some objects from other objects";

My second cut: "You need to put the ST_Intersects () function in order, so that as a result of its operation, some objects CUT other objects."

The whole operation is completed, I hope none of the patients were injured and did not spill a single drop of blood ... With you there was a kind surgeon Mr. Carver ... :-(...O.S.

Comment: this is poor practice for this example because an island that just hits the purple polygon will get selected. st_intersection should be used to cut the geometries. or at least st_within() or st_contains

Comment: You can use ST_Intersection with ST_Intresects ...